# Multiple projects vs multiple script files in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Recently, I have been using some simple scripts (thanks to people here at Stack Overflow and at Google Sheet Forum) in some of my Google spreadsheets: scripts for -

1. getting dates in column B, if there is data in column A,
2. getting the sheet name in a cell,
3. ImportRange through script, etc.

My question is --- do I need to keep all these scripts as separate projects (which is what I am currently doing), or can I put each script in separate script files and let them be within a single project, or else, should I put all the functions/scripts within a single script file within a single project?

Why I am asking this because my spreadsheets are running quite slow lately. And would like to know which is the best scenario, if at all, out of the above three, to speed up the spreadsheet.

Comment: You can make multiple script files inside a single project and use them as usual.

Comment: The Apps Script code editor runs in your browser, as opposed to running from software from your hard drive.  So, the Apps Script code editor is a "Web App."  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Your question is about general usage of a Web App.  It might be a better question for the [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) community.

Comment: @SandyGood: According to [help/on-topic] questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are allowed. IMHO the Apps Script editor belongs to this category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the Apps Script project files affects per-se the performance of a spreadsheet.

One basic step to improve a spreadsheet performance is to check if it's possible to reduce the number of sheets, columns, rows and formulas in order to reduce the spreadsheet size and complexity.

I.E. some calculations are required to be done only one time. Once the calculation was made, replace the formulas by their result (paste as values could by handy for this).